# How use $_SESSION to retrieve data from database and using it to query database

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to use the details of a login user to query a database using `$_SESSION`:

```
<div class="content-box">
  <div class="label" style="color: #e40046;">Referrals</div>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>

        <?php
          include('../db.php');

          $uploaduser = $_SESSION['username'];

          $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$uploaduser'";

          $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

          while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
            $name = $res['firstname'];
            $email = $res['email'];
            $ref = $res['affcode'];
          }
    
          $count = 1;

          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refBy=?");
          $stmt->bind_param("s", $ref);
          $stmt->execute();

          $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>       
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td><?php echo $row["firstname"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row["lastname"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php $count++; } ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works perfectly well. Is there a better/simplier way to achieve this?

Comment: Better way would be to stick to OOP + using a template engine

Answer (score 0):

You could short it a bit. And if I see this right you don't use `$name` and `$email` anywhere.

That would be my solution:

```
<div class="content-box">
  <div class="label" style="color: #e40046;">Referrals</div>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>

        <?php
          include_once('../db.php');

          $query = "SELECT affcode FROM users WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";

          $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

          while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)) {
            $ref = $res['affcode'];
          }
    
          $count = 1;

          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE refBy=?");
          $stmt->bind_param("s", $ref);
          $stmt->execute();
    
          while ($row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo <<<HEREDOC
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>{$row["firstname"]}</td>
              <td>{$row["lastname"]}</td>
            </tr>
            HEREDOC;
            $count++;
          } ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I don't get dor what's `$count` for